# How to remove event listener if function has parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am adding a listener in a function, but before doing so I am removing any old listeners. I think the removing is not working because it keeps calling the listener function twice after clicking on it.

```
 function remove_this_rfid(rfid_id, loc_id) {
  let delete_rfid_button = document.getElementById("confirm_delete_rfid_id");
  delete_rfid_button.removeEventListener("click", remove_this_rfid_confirm);
  delete_rfid_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    remove_this_rfid_confirm(rfid_id, loc_id);
  }, false);
}

function remove_this_rfid_confirm(rfid_id, loc_id) { 
  //this function has an Ajax call, which is executed twice when I click on the button after the first time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out even a better solution to this, using pure JS:

```
 var delete_rfid_button = document.getElementById("confirm_delete_rfid_id");
 delete_rfid_button.removeAttribute("onclick");
 delete_rfid_button.setAttribute('onclick', 'remove_this_rfid_confirm('+rfid_id + ','+ loc_id+')');
```

it also makes the code less cumbersome.